# wxPython: purpose SetScale() function in ScrolledWindow class?

Tags: wxpython

What does the SetScale() function in the ScrolledWindow class of wxPython do?

I've been looking in vain for an easy way to do browser-style whole-page Panel zooming and ran across this, but it doesn't seem to do anything.  It's not even showing up in the wxWidget docs.